# Apache redirect some url to homepage

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, redirect

I am trying to implement a simple rewrite, but looks like i am doing something wrong. What I am trying to do is that I have a url **blog.example.com/articles/** which gives me 404 , and other urls are **blog.example.com/articles/abc**, **blog.example.com/articles/xyz** etc , which works fine, so I want **blog.example.com/articles/** to show me home page which is **blog.example.com** instead of 404, but i don't want any other url ,which has something like /articles/* to be affected by that rule.

This is what I have tried so far

```
RewriteRule ^/articles$ /index.php [R=302]
```

which does not work

I have tried the redirection as well

```
Redirect "/articles" "http://blog.example.com/"
```

I works but it changes the url in the browser and also affects all other urls starting with **/articles**

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use proxypass, for that enable mod_proxy in apache.

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

then allow your server to use apache as proxy

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On
<Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
</Proxy>
```

Now you can write rewrite rule as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /articles$ http://blog.example.com [P,L]
```

Now when url matching **blog.example.com/articles** will come , it will fetch the result from **blog.example.com** without changing the url in the browser. It will only send the url **blog.example.com/articles** through tother urhe proxy, urls are affected.

Comment: yes that works.